# Laravel redirect to login page after session timeout

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

I have a Laravel App (5.8) where there's a session timeout after a while due to inactivity. But the page remains there until the user maybe tries to click on something and then it goes to the login page.

Now is it a good idea to invoke meta redirection to solve the issue?

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="{{ config('session.lifetime') * 60 }}; url = {{ route('login') }}" />`

What we're trying to achieve here is showing the login page (redirecting there automatically) after the timeout, but i'm trying to figure out how to do it, is this an okay method where the user *can* actually open multiple tabs on different times? or is there a better full proof way to do it.

Comment: You don't need to specify `url`. There is built in middleware that is inside `auth` key, redirects user to login page if unauthenticated. So refreshing page is a good idea.

Comment: ok, but is it a good solution where user can open multiple tabs? for instance, suppose timeout is 1hour, now if the user opens a 2nd tab 10 mins later, won't the new time will be 1hr where as the 1st tab will refresh after 50 mins where it's not timeout and thus extend the time more because of the refresh activity?

Comment: first tab will not refresh after 50 min. If user opens new tab it will change in all application session. I mean first page will refresh after 1 hour as well

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear before, what i meant if the 2nd tab opened after 10mins then the 1st tab will refresh after 50 mins as 10mins passed already. now here's my confusion, due to the opening of 2nd tab, as you've mentioned, it will change in all app session aka get 60mins again from now on, is that correct? now if so, then the refresh of the 1st tab will not get the login page, but rather will increase the session timeout 60 mins more, will that be the case or i misunderstood it completely?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That will be the case.

Comment: so that seems like a big problem, and my question was related to that, trying meta refresh/redirect to achieve that maybe not a good idea after all, and hence i'm looking for a better solution, thank you!

Comment: Hmm. Sorry I didn't understood you well at first. I am glad if I helped for anything.

Comment: thanks! so do you have any suggestion about how to make sure that the user will be redirected to login page after session timeout?